# How to insert data in hierarchical order in mongodb in node.js application?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I am trying to insert data in mongodb in my node.js application. But my post request is creating new article in the document everytime.

```
0:Object
_v:0
_id:"56e1825c9d7b67156d2f38b2"
actor:"FirstActor"
productName:"Kernal"

1:Object
_v:0
_id:"56e1832a9c363cd405d980ee"
actor:"SecondActor"
productName:"Kernal"
```

My code is creating a new obect with a uniquee id every time. What I want is like :

```
0:Object
_v:0
_id:"56e1825c9d7b67156d2f38b2"
actor:{"FirstActor","Second Actor"}
productName:"Kernal"
```

If the productName is same it should not create a new object.

Code I have written looks like:

```
  app.post('/addActor',function(req, res) {

        console.log("Calling to Adding Actor");
        console.log(req.body);
        impactMap.create({

            productName : req.body.productName,
            actor : req.body.actor,

            /*done : false*/
        }, function(err, data) {
            if (err)
                res.send(err);

            // get and return all the todos after you create another
            impactMap.find(function(err, data) {
                if (err)
                    res.send(err)
                res.json(data);
            });
        });

    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's creating a new object every time because you're calling `create` every time. What you're looking for is `upsert`:

```
impactMap.updateOne(
  { productName: req.body.productName },
  { $push: { actor: req.body.actor } },
  { upsert: true }
}, function (err, data) {
  // callback code can stay the same
});
```

This may not work on existing documents as it doesn't seem like you created them with `actor` as an array. You'll want to update your model as such:

```
mongoose.model('impactMap', {
  ...
  actor: [{ type: 'string' }],
  ...
});
```

Comment: This is how my document schema looks like    
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

module.exports = mongoose.model('ImpactMap', {

    productName:String,
    actor: { type:'string' },
    impact: { type:'string' },
    activity: { type:'string' },

});

Comment: Use ... actor: [{ type: 'string' }], ... I'll update my answer.

Comment: Data I am getting is in "actor": [
      "dwqwqqw","dskllkd"
    ]   I want it to be in "actor": [
      "name":"dwqwqqw", "name", "dskllkd"
    ]. Would it be possible?

Comment: Yes. When you add your actors add them as an object: `{ $push: { actor: { name: req.body.actor } } }`. Likewise, update the schema: `[{ name: String }]`.